# Mit Scheme Installation Error in Ubuntu (Environment Variable Settings)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, scheme, mit-scheme

I'm trying to install MIT-Scheme in Ubuntu on Windows 10. 
I downloaded the tar-file from the Mit-Scheme website.

I run the command `tar -xzf mit-scheme-9.2.tar.gz`. Then `cd mit-scheme-9.2/`. Then `cd src`. Then `./configure`.
However, I get the error logs below. Appreciate some advise. Thanks.

```
mingerz@DESKTOP-BMERQIM:~/mit-scheme-9.2/src$ ./configure
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for native-code support... yes, for x86-64
checking for an existing MIT/GNU Scheme installation... configure: error:
This script needs an existing MIT/GNU Scheme installation to function,
but the following programs do not run it:

   mit-scheme-x86-64
   mit-scheme

If you have installed MIT/GNU Scheme in an unusual location, set the
environment variable MIT_SCHEME_EXE to the name or pathname of the
MIT/GNU Scheme executable, which is usually `mit-scheme' or
`/usr/local/bin/mit-scheme', and set the environment variable
MITSCHEME_LIBRARY_PATH to the pathname of the MIT/GNU Scheme library
directory, which is usually `/usr/local/lib/mit-scheme-x86-64'.
```

I dont understand how to implement the suggestion it is asking me to in regards to the environment variable.

Comment: As it says, the build script needs an existing MIT/GNU Scheme installation. Why don't you install a pre-built version?

Comment: So how was that pre-built binary compiled?

Comment: Ok, so is installing Scheme only for Computer Science alumni or is there a way to make it? I do not understand why the guide in https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/stable/mit-scheme-user/Unix-Installation.html mentions `./configure` step when obviously it needs the Scheme already installed. It is a bit idiotic, because following the steps does not result in having Scheme installed, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

---

> This script needs an existing MIT/GNU Scheme installation to function

$ `sudo apt-get install mit-scheme` : http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mit-scheme&searchon=names

---

Answer (score -1):

Facing same issue on mac.
Instead of building from source, installing package helped in my case.

A. Installing Binary :

1. Get MIT-scheme (package) for Ubunto from MIT site http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/
2. Install it
3. Alias mit_scheme in ~/.bash_profile -->

alias mit-scheme=" path to MIT_scheme on your machine"

eg. alias mit-scheme="/Applications/MIT-Scheme.app/Contents/Resources/mit-scheme"
So that you can access it from bash.

---

B. If building from source, this link might be helpful.
https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/users/gjs/6.945/dont-panic/

And they say --> Don't Panic

Comment: Step 2 of your answer is building from source, except that you downloaded it from a different location.

Comment: Same thing. I can understand your confusion. That page you linked indeed ships the binaries for OS X, so it must have worked for you. But OP is in Ubuntu and, despite the page saying "Linux binaries", it actually contains the source for Linux, so step 2 from your answer is still building from source.